# How and where do you validate business rules in an Asp.net MVC applicatin?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and while developing my first application, I have a few questions.

One is: which is the best way to validate business rules?

In my `Edit` post method, for example, I check `ModelState.IsValid` to be sure that inserted data is in a valid state (employee name is inserted, has the correct length, etc..). But how to check if business rules are ok?

For example, let's say that in my `Employee` edit view, the user can select a new job grade for the employee. With `ModelState.IsValid` I can check whether a jobgrade has been selected, but I have to check if the `jobGrade` selected has been assigned to that employee in the past (this breaks a business rule) or that the start date inserted for the new jobgrade (already validated with `ModelState`) must be grater than the starting date for the current jobGrade. And so on.

How would you do all these validations?

Something like this ?

```
try
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if !(checkJobGradeAssignment(viewModel.jobGradeId))
        {
            throw new Exception("The job grade has already been assigned to the employee")
        }

        if !(checkjobGradeDate(viewModel.jobGradeStartDate))
        {
            throw new exception("The start date is not valid.")
        }

        // other validations

        // other code
    }
    else
    {
        return View(viewModel)
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(ex.message)
    return View(viewModel)
}
```

In my case I have only model (and view model) classes, controllers and views - no tiers.

Thanks.